# encoding with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have text that is in the database like this :    `that does&#96;nt`

I'm upgrading this application and this is how it shows in MVC when I try to display it using this command:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.adDescription)
```

I've tried to use the `Html.Encode` but I don't see a change.  is there something I can do outside of updating the data in the DB to get it to display correctly?

**Update - 2nd part of question:**

How can I convert this bad text into good text when in Editing mode:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.adDescription)
```

I keep getting dangerous text errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@Model.ContentText))
```

Replace `ContentText` with your html code.

Can you try following?

```
<textarea>@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@Model.ContentText))</textarea>
```

or if that is a input field. try accordingly.

Comment: would that be in the view or the controller?

Comment: you need to put that in your view.

Comment: Ok that seems to work...  How can I do it inside an EditorFor?  I'll update my question

Comment: I'm getting : Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions. - I updated my question with code

Comment: what about it is not good?  i'm not denying that it isn't good, I'm just wondering what you are seeing?

Comment: you shouldnt do : @{var desc = @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.adDescription);
        @Html.EditorFor(model => HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@desc.ToString()));
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.adExpirationDate);
        }

Comment: wtf is `var desc` there.